# Need to select text of selected dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a dropdown with values. I have an array array with a list of values that will match the drop down values.  If the value of text option of the dropdown exists in the array, it shouldn't show in the dropdown as an option.  I am stuck on the approach I should use.  This is what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
Car Plates: 
<select title='car/id' id='car_x0020_Plate_x002f'>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">none</option>
  <option value="16">233-jj2</option>
  <option value="10">934-zxy</option>
  <option value="90">330-nbh</option>
  <option value="11">930-orj</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var hideOption = ['233-jj2', '330-nbh']

var e = document.querySelector([id^='car']);
var strUser = e.value;
                               
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

for (var x=0; x<hideOption.length; x++){
  if (hideOption[x] === strUser){
    //remove from dropdown
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you've got a typo: `lenght`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your idea in a very simple way, if you have any question please tell me

```js
var hideOption = ['233-jj2', '330-nbh'],
    select = document.getElementById("select");

for (let i = 0; i < hideOption.length; i = i + 1) {
    for (let t = 1; t < select.options.length; t = t + 1) {
        if (hideOption[i] == select.options[t].textContent) {
            select.options[t].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
Car Plates: 
<select title='car/id' id='select'>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">none</option>
  <option value="16">233-jj2</option>
  <option value="10">934-zxy</option>
  <option value="90">330-nbh</option>
  <option value="11">930-orj</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my id will have the funky name   id='car_x0020_Plate_x002f'.  It is generated.  How can I get your solution to work with that?

Comment: you can change my id to your id, change select to car_x0020_Plate_x002f,

Or

you can work with classname instead of the id:
put this code in javascript 
select = document.getElementsByClassName("yourselectclassname")[0];


instead of
select = document.getElementById("select");


yourselectclassname this class give it to the select in html

<select class="yourselectclassname" > ...

If you have any question just tell me, like if you want another method, and you only want to work with the id.

Comment: I will give you another method if you cannot add a class to your select and only you want to work with the id

Comment: Add This code at the top of your javascript code


`var selectall = document.querySelectorAll('select');`

`var select;`

for (var i = 0; i < selectall.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (selectall[i].getAttribute("id") != undefined) {
        if (selectall[i].getAttribute("id").indexOf("car") != -1) {
            select = selectall[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

// remove this: select = document.getElementById("select");

Than all your code will works fine, if you have any question ask me, everything has a solution

Comment: I have a problem in writing the code in the comment, it`s not beautiful, if there is an another way you know to give you the code just tell me to do it, just read first what I told you, If this is what you want I will put a new answer and include everything in it.

Answer (score 1):

// remove from dropdown
use this code to remove from dropdown
e.removeChild(e.options[e.selectedIndex])

you can use this also
e.selectedOptions[0].remove()

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hideOption = ['233-jj2', '330-nbh']

var e = document.querySelector("[id^='car']");
var selTextArr = Array.from(e.options).map(option => option.text)
                               
for (var x=0; x<selTextArr.length; x++){
  if (hideOption.includes(selTextArr[x])){
    e.remove(x)
  }
}
```

```html
Car Plates: 
<select title='car/id' id='car_x0020_Plate_x002f'>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">none</option>
  <option value="16">233-jj2</option>
  <option value="10">934-zxy</option>
  <option value="90">330-nbh</option>
  <option value="11">930-orj</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var options = document.querySelector("[id^='car']").children;
var hideOption = ['233-jj2', '330-nbh']

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    if(hideOption.indexOf(options[i].text) > -1){
        options[i].remove();
    }
}
```